# "Hey Siri" doesn’t run if iPad locked and Smart Cover Closed in iOS 11

Tags: ipad, siri, ios

I have an iPad Pro 9.7 Wifi & Cellular 128 GB.  In iOS 10.3.3, I could call Siri with "Hey Siri" keyword even if iPad locked and Smart Cover closed. Now, I upgraded my device to iOS 11. The "Hey Siri" keyword runs only if iPad locked and Smart Cover is open. However; if iPad locked and Smart Cover closed, it doesn’t work. I've been using my iPad (in a Smart Cover) for "Hey Siri what is the degree in my room" for about a year now. It stopped responding only after updating to iOS 11. "Hey Siri" and "Allow Siri while locked" toggles are checked in Settings also.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with iOS 11. Currently there is no way to turn "Hey Siri" back on with the Smart Cover covering the iPad's screen.

[Please provide feedback to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/ipad.html) so the feature can be brought back in future releases of iOS 11.

Comment: Also, there is now code to see which device is closest to you when you say “Hey Siri” - I would be sure there’s not a phone or watch intercepting the request believing they are closer (and that’s a nice workaround if you have the others to talk to while your iPad gently sleeps),

Comment: @bmike That's been around since iOS 10, so it's possible if OP has got a new device, but wouldn't be a factor specifically from the upgrade from 10.3.3, where OP says it was working fine.